# Best practice for handling buffers

Tags: embedded, software, best-practice

I'm writing some evaluation code with a lot of rx/tx operations, using the same two buffers and I started to think about how this could easily go very wrong.

I can argue that it is nice to clear/reinitialize the buffers with 0's or any other val for that matter for safety purpose, and it's not like my MCU can't spare the extra X ms operations.

But at the same time I could also argue that flushing them is just bloat operations as the program behaves as it should.

What is the best practice / industry standard when it comes to handling buffers continuously overwritten? Is flushing the buffers after each operation, like wearing a life jacket on land ?

```
void IIS328DQ_Read_All(void)
{
  txbuf[0] = IIS328DQ_REG_OUT_X_H;
  txbuf[1] = IIS328DQ_REG_OUT_X_L;
  txbuf[2] = IIS328DQ_REG_OUT_Y_H;
  txbuf[3] = IIS328DQ_REG_OUT_Y_L;
  txbuf[4] = IIS328DQ_REG_OUT_Z_H;
  txbuf[5] = IIS328DQ_REG_OUT_Z_L;

  // Request X axis high and low bytes
  ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, IIS328DQSADWR, &txbuf[0], 2, 
  HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, IIS328DQSADRD, &rxbuf[0], 2, 
  HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  // Request Y axis high and low bytes
  ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, IIS328DQSADWR, &txbuf[2], 2, 
  HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, IIS328DQSADRD, &rxbuf[2], 2, 
  HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  // Request Z axis high and low bytes
  ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, IIS328DQSADWR, &txbuf[4], 2, 
  HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, IIS328DQSADRD, &rxbuf[4], 2, 
  HAL_MAX_DELAY);


 // Combine high and low bytes 0b00001111+00001111 (Endianness) to 16 bit int
 x_raw = ((int16_t)rxbuf[0]<<8) + rxbuf[1];
 // Shift the 16 bits to a 12-bit representation
 x_raw = x_raw >> 4;
 y_raw = ((int16_t)rxbuf[2]<<8) + rxbuf[3];
 y_raw = y_raw >> 4;
 z_raw = ((int16_t)rxbuf[4]<<8) + rxbuf[5];
 z_raw = z_raw >> 4;

 // FS bits set to 00 - min 0.9 | typ 0.98 | max 1.1
 // convert raw data using sensitivity (0.98mg/digit ~ normal mode)
 axisArr[0] = x_raw * Sensitivity;
 axisArr[1] = y_raw * Sensitivity;
 axisArr[2] = z_raw * Sensitivity;
 clearBuf();
 }
```

clearBuf() simply fills the rx/tx buffers with 0's up to sizeof()

Comment: I must admit I see no advantage of zeroing here, whatsoever. Could you explain what *safety* gain this has in the context of such sample buffers?

Comment: I was thinking the safety perspective would be to start over with a completely 0'ed buffer so no extra bytes are written if you mess up in SW say you need to write 4 bytes but you accidentally write 5, the 5th would just be 0 in our case. I don't really know, one could just say.. well then don't screw up :)

Comment: I still don't understand why overwriting with zeros is *safer* than overwriting your last samples? That seems to make no sense to me. Or why reading zeros is *safer* than reading previous samples?

Comment: "so no extra bytes are written if you mess up in software": not true, you're writing a  defined number of zeros, aren't you? If you wrote samples after the end of your buffer, that'd be totally unaffected by your zeroing. Also, zeroing those would have no helpful effect, would it?

Comment: Okay say that we write 5 bytes from arr[0..4] = 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 and we finish that operation. Then we write another 4 bytes from arr[0..3] 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 but now we accidentally mess up and we write 5 bytes instead of the 4 we wanted from our arr[ ] and we write 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 and 0x05, if we cleared it all it would be a 0x00 or 0xFF or some other byte val that is not recognized as a command by the device at all. That is my only arguement, but as the topic says am in doubt whether or not this is overkill.

Comment: Where the operation of the programme (and therefore the buffers) is fixed, as in this case, I see no reason or advantage to clearing the buffers at the end. It is in cases where the operation is *not* deterministic (unknown amount of data, for instance) that something needs to be done. (I often use a circular buffer and maintain a count).

Comment: @Sorenp yeah, but you're not taking commands out of that buffer. Also, if you presume that you have a bug in something as fundamental as writing the right amount of data, you also can't assume you're interpreting zeros correctly, can you?

Comment: Thanks for the input @PeterSmith I always enjoy hearing what others are doing / problems they have encountered !

Comment: On the contrary, actually: if you assume (and that's a realistic assumption for most software!) that there's some bugs, then it's usually desirable to write as little as possible – especially in a microcontroller context – since that increases the time during which race conditions could occur.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it is more a hypothetical question, assuming that something happens to corrupt the buffer between write cycles, how common is that even?

Comment: You tell me - it's your microcontroller's firmware! Is there something else writing to that section? If so, I don't see any synchronization barriers in your code. If not, then the likelihood of accidentally writing something is the likelihood of silicon defects and random bit flips. That's low, as in it's unlikely you'll ever see that.

Comment: Nah the buffers are written to sequentially and I'll implement some callbacks later, I don't know I need to ... pontificate.. on this some more, for now I will accept that it is overkill when working with fixed sets of data :) thank you for the inputs

Comment: please don't add code as an image

Comment: fixed just easier to snip it to mark it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific example, yes I would continue to clear the buffers and call your `clearBuf()` function.

Why? Mainly because you aren't even handling that return status from your I2C tx and rx functions.

What happens if your device suddenly becomes unreachable via I2C and all your Receive calls are failing? I don't know what the `HAL_I2C_Master_Receive` does to the buffer when timeout duration is reached without looking in depth at their specific implementation but there's a decent chance they just leave the buffer untouched.

The result could be, if not caught via checking return status or other special handling, that you continue to process data as if it is not changing at all.

Real process data will typically be something non-zero so if you're reading a data stream that goes something like `[1.56, 1.54, 1.58, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` a user may be alerted to your device being bad even if you didn't account for handling the specific error condition encountered (such as the one present in your code).

Evaluating this single failure mode of loss of I2C communication for two possible data stream scenarios either:

1. Your data stream is typically zero and simply doesn't respond to changes due to the failure
2. Your data stream is typically non-zero and has suddenly zero'd out due to the failure

Clearing your buffers makes the error condition visible in the second scenario even if it doesn't improve things for the first one.

So--you could (and should) fix your error handling to alleviate this particular issue, but what else are you missing? Sensors go bad, I2C operations fail, power can fluctuate, are you making sure you don't lie to your users?

Comment: "you aren't even handling that return status from your I2C tx and rx functions." I removed that part as it made the piece of code way to big for posting here. I do have have asserts and some custom err codes. But thanks for the input, its very valid.